# Ice Cream Cone on curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am part of a digital animation class, and I need to create an ice cream cone following the tutorials by the Blender Nation. However, I'm not been able to curve my ice cream around the bezier curve. I would be grateful for any advice on how to move past this part.

[image]

Comment: What part of the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvTrZ0soo_Q) is not clear? where do you have problems?

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for offering to help. I'm having issues with the last step of the second part. I'm not being able to curve my ice cream around the bezier curve using the curve modifier. My teacher and fellow classmates, via the internet, cannot pinpoint what I'm doing wrong, They claimed that I should just restart, but I keep on facing this problem.

Comment: Looks like you under follow curve, not curve modifier

Comment: Thank you for the help!